# How to import a CSS file in a React Component on Electron

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, electron

I have seen that it is used

```
import React from 'react';
import './cssName.css';
```

but it does not work for me, I am working on the electron app and add react as shown here

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you do not have a build process set up. You will need to setup webpack or something like that to be able to import css.

I suggest you read this article: https://flaviocopes.com/react-electron/.